# given the minimal polynomial of matrix $A^2$ find minimal polynomials and Jordan forms of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

I'm refreshing some linear algebra and came across this question:
Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$ and suppose the minimal polynomial of its square is $\phi_{A^2}=(x-1)^2$. Now we're asked to give all possible minimal polynomials of matrix $A$ with their respective Jordan normal form.
My approach would be to just fill in $A^2$ in the minimal polynomial to get: $(A^2-I)^2=(A-I)^2(A+I)^2=0$. This would then lead to the Jordan form being:
$J=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$.
I suppose the minimal polynomial of $A$ could also be $(x-1)(x+1)^2$ or $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ or $(x-1)(x+1)$ each with their respective Jordan form but I don't see whether there's a thinking process behind it. like for example the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ limiting some of these from being possible but I don't see why.
Any help or hint would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $(A^2-I)^2 = 0$ but $A^2 - I \ne 0$.  The minimal polynomial of
$A$ divides $(x^2-1)^2 = (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$ but does not divide $x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$.
The possibilities are then $(x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$, $(x-1)^2 (x+1)$, $(x-1)^2$, $(x-1)(x+1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$.  For each of those it's easy to give an example.

Comment: @rikdb Note that for each of $(x-1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ there are two possible Jordan forms.

Comment: Since the invariant system could be $\{2,1,1\}$ as wel as $\{2,2\}$ ?